# Do effects that say "per condition" or "per boon" also work with stacks of the same condition/boon?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I wonder whether skills and traits that say they do something "per condition" or "per boon" on a certain target have the same effect when there are multiple conditions or boons as when there is an equal number of stacks of the same condition.

For example, let's take the Necromancer skill [Feast of Corruption](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Feast_of_Corruption) which states that it does more damage based on the number of conditions on the target. Imagine my target has 1 poison, 1 bleeding and 1 blind condition, the skill has it's damage increased 3 times. Now does the skill have its damage increased also 3 times when the only conditions on the target are 3 stacks of bleeding?

Comment: According to the discussion page on the wiki page you linked to, it 's unique conditions, not stacks of the same condition.

Comment: @DavidYell Agree, but that comment was never confirmed and it was from pre-release (2012-06-17). I was hoping someone could give a definite answer for the released game version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No, stacks of the same condition do not count as multiple conditions.**

Test 1:
On my guardian, got something to drop 7 or 8 stacks of bleed on me. Used a skill that removes 1 condition, all bleed stacks removed.

Test 2:
Took my necro to the heavy armor target golems in PvP isle. Feast of Corruption with no conditions does 420-430 damage. Feast of Corruption with cripple & 3 stacks of bleed does 530-550 damage (Grasping Dead immediately followed by Feast of Corruption). Feast of Corruption with poison & 9-12 stacks of bleed also did 530-550 damage (spam wand 1 until it had enough bleed, then Feast of Corruption). Feast of Corruption with poison, cripple, and bleed (3-4 stacks) did about 600 damage (3 hits of wand 1, then Grasping Dead, then Feast of Corruption).

Comment: For science! +1

Comment: Good answer... testing is always the best way... :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think so. Conditions stack up. For effect stacking, most conditions stack in duration while bleeding and confusion stack in intensity. A guardian can use a shout which lets all people near apply a fire condition with their first spell. That'd mean Feast of Corruption would do damage bigtime.

But, it doesn't. Stacking conditions of the same type doesn't count as having that many conditions, but only 1 condition. That would normally mean you have more time to cast Feast of Corruption, though.

Comment: Have an upvote for the sheer confusing nature of your answer.

Comment: I don't get it!